# Wordpress Stripping SVG Path Code in Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, svg

Im having issues trying to insert svg path code into the footer of my website using the Wordpress Customizer menu. It seems Wordpress is stripping the code from:

```
<div class="wcpay-connect-account-page-payment-methods"><svg width="51" height="35" viewBox="0 0 51 35" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="50" height="34" rx="3.5" fill="white" stroke="#F3F3F3"></rect>
<path d="path...." fill="#15195A"></path>
<path d="path...." fill="#15195A"></path>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="path...." fill="#15195A"></path>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="path...." fill="#15195A"></path>
```

to:

```
<div class="wcpay-connect-account-page-payment-methods"></div>
```

Theme: Oceanwp-3.1.2

SVG Paths do load within main page content just not in the footer.

I have tried looking around for different code snippets to add into my functions file to disable the stripping of SVG tags but none seem to have worked.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could enable SVG path codes/stop them from being stripped within my footer?